# How to avoid to install some dependencies that I do not need in an angluar 10 app?

Tags: angular, babeljs, npm-install, dependency-management

I'm working on an angular 10 app. in my `package.json` I do not have anything about `@babel`, but when I luch `npm install` I am having an error :

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://private_repo/repository/npm-all/@babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin/-/helper-create-class-features-plugin-7.14.2.tgz
```

What dependency can install `@babel` ?

Answer (score -1):

Npm install will download all your dependencies and the dependencies of your dependencies, so, one of them use @Babel.

You will find the error when look into your dependencies and check how is using this `http://private_repo/repository...`.

Also, try install the packages if Yarn.